# Charles Map local - Ignore initial request of same URL with OPTIONS method and map second with GET request

Tags: charles-proxy

I am trying to stub out a request locally with a response saved within a local file. This is working fine however I need to get to ignore an initial request of the same URL but with a Method type of Options.

The problem is, the local mapping is being mapped to this request instead of the Intended GET request which leads to an error. Is There away way I can specify something extra so the initial options request which comes back is ignored.

[Example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iYVMj.png)

Hope this clear enough

Thanks.

Comment: This is a major limitation of Charles, and is discussed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52048842/562978).

Answer (score 0):

It's a limitation of Charles, that doesn't allow you to specify the matching HTTP Method.

I suggest using other tools like [Proxyman](https://proxyman.io/blog/2020/02/Change-HTTP-status-codes-for-UI-testing.html), that you can define which Method you need for the Map Local Tool. You can map entire Response HTTP Message (Includes Header and Status Code as well)

[image]