# How to use Charles' rewrite tool only on certain methods?

Tags: charles-proxy

I'm using [Charles' Rewrite Tool](https://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/tools/rewrite/) to change 200 responses to 400 in order to test failing API calls. However, the rewrite is triggering on the `Options` request. I'd like to only have it trigger on the `Get` or `Post` requests and allow the `Options` requests through. Is this possible using Charles?

[image: Rewrite Screen]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We were able to work around the issue by assuming that OPTIONS would always return an empty body.

The below Regex values will match for GET (because it has a response body) and not match for OPTIONS (because it doesn't have a response body).

> \{[\S\s]*\}

or

> \[[\S\s]*\]

[image: Rewrite Rule]

Comment: Hi, I don't get what are you doing. You said you want to bypass the OPTION method and let POST,GET, PUT method return error server error 400. There's no place for updating the response to 400 based on your update

Answer (score 6):

I think Charles does not have this option, which is really a pitty, because it seems to be easy to implement and it would open the doors to the API world.

I would suggest you to ask Karl (the author and main developer) for this new feature at the [contact](https://www.charlesproxy.com/support/contact/) section of the site.

Answer (score 6):

We have this exact same need to mock API responses.  Since the Rewrite tool doesn't support this feature, we have setup [Breakpoints](https://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/proxying/breakpoints/) on the responses we want to mock, once the breakpoint is hit, we change the response to whatever we want.  It works, but is less than ideal.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, Charles doesn't have this feature to filter out which the Request that has certain HTTP Method.

It's not a direct answer, but you can achieve with [Scripting](https://docs.proxyman.io/scripting/script) tool from [Proxyman](https://docs.proxyman.io)

[image: scripting to change https status code]

```js
function onResponse(context, url, request, response) {

  // Update status Code
  response.statusCode = 500;

  // Done
  return response;
}
```

Here is the [Snippet Code](https://docs.proxyman.io/scripting/snippet-code) that you can do with JS Code.

Disclaimer: I'm a creator of Proxyman. Since there are many people who struggle with this problem, hopefully, the Scripting tool can help you.

Answer (score 1):

In Charles, you can use Breakpoints tools. FYR: https://tanaschita.com/20220307-manipulating-network-requests-and-responses-with-charles/.

Answer (score 0):

A preflight request *normally* responds with http status code `204 No Content`, which makes it easy to separate from the GET response with status code `200 OK`. In these cases, you can simply match on the response status in the rewrite rule to replace only the GET response status.

[image: preflight and corresponding get requests]

[image: Charles Proxy rewrite rule]