# Charles:How to record the http request exclude the OPTIONS schema?

Tags: http, charles-proxy

In the "Recording Settings" menu, how to filter the request which "method" is "OPTIONS". I want to exclude (or include) by schema, like POST/GET/PUT, etc.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, Charles does not have any option to filter out http requests by method.

You can see these posts which are closely related if you want some more info about this topic:

- [How to use Charles' rewrite tool only on certain methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52048842/how-to-use-charles-rewrite-tool-only-on-certain-methods/52109618#52109618)
- [Charles Proxy: Map to GET Request instead of OPTIONS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53087959/charles-proxy-map-to-get-request-instead-of-options/53151214#53151214)