# Charles Proxy: Map to GET Request instead of OPTIONS

Tags: charles-proxy

Is there a way to do a local mapping in Charles based on a specific request? My API makes both a OPTIONS request followed by a GET request.

When I do a local mapping in Charles, it maps the response to that OPTIONS request. I would like it to map the response to the GET request instead.

Is there a way around this? I'm new to this tool.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Stackoverflow closed the question, but the answer is to use breakpoints and put a breakpoint for the response, then edit the response and execute it.

Answer (score 2):

I think this has already been discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52048842/how-to-use-charles-rewrite-tool-only-on-certain-methods/52109618#52109618).

As it is said there, Charles does not provide any way to be able to distinguish between different HTTP requests by its method, but you may be able to workaround it by filtering by empty body requests.

Answer (score 2):

It's probably off-topic but one way to solve this problem is to disable the OPTIONS request..

> open -na Google\ Chrome --args --disable-web-security --user-data-dir=$HOME/profile-folder-name

Then, Chrome & Charles proxy can work together